# AWS update request, variable parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am kind of new into the AWS console and what not, I just wrote my own API (with the help of tutorials) and was wondering the following, can I update my product conditionally? My current param from the call looks like:

```
    TableName: "product",
    Key: {
        product_id: event.pathParameters.id
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET price_buyin = :price_buyin, price_sell = :price_sell, price_grit = :price_grit, note = :note, status_code = :status_code, producttype_id = :producttype_id, handled_by = :handled_by, handled_number = :handled_number, productsize_id = :productsize_id, processed_date = :processed_date",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":price_buyin": data.price_buyin ? data.price_buyin : 0,
        ":price_sell": data.price_sell ? data.price_sell : 0,
        ":price_grit": data.price_grit ? data.price_grit : 0,
        ":status_code": data.status_code ? data.status_code : 0,
        ":processed_date": data.processed_date ? data.processed_date : 0,
        ":producttype_id": data.producttype_id ? data.producttype_id : 0,
        ":handled_number": data.handled_number ? data.handled_number : 0,
        ":productsize_id": data.productsize_id ? data.productsize_id : 0,
        ":note": data.note ? data.note : "empty",
        ":handled_by": data.handled_by ? data.handled_by : "empty"
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
```

I want to be able to update, lets say; price_buyin, but when I dont add the other values, they automatically become 0. Is there some way to say to only update price_buyin?

Thank you in advance!

Greetings,

Bram

Comment: This appears to be for DynamoDB — is that correct? If so, please add DynamoDB as a tag.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Even if you put undefined dynamodb throws error.